# Solving $ \Delta \Phi = \pi \left[ \sin(\theta_e) \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi_e - \phi) + \cos(\theta_e) \cos(\theta) \right]$ for unknown angles?

Tags: trigonometry

I am examining the problem of determining unknown angles in an antenna array system, where the phase shift equation is given as:

$$
\Delta \Phi = \pi \left[ \sin(\theta_e) \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi_e - \phi) + \cos(\theta_e) \cos(\theta) \right]
$$

In this scenario, $ \Delta \Phi $ represents the phase shift, and I have multiple phase shifts given, such as $ \Delta \Phi_1, \Delta \Phi_2, \ldots $, corresponding to different configurations or conditions. The variables $ \theta_e, \phi_e, \theta, \phi $ are all unknown angles related to the antenna array's elements and the desired beam directions.

My questions are:

1. Is there an established analytical method to solve for the unknown angles $ \theta_e, \phi_e, \theta, \phi $ based on the given phase shifts $ \Delta \Phi_1, \Delta \Phi_2, \ldots $?
2. Would knowing the incident angles $\theta, \phi $ in advance simplify the problem, and if so, how could this be leveraged mathematically to solve for the remaining unknown angles $(\theta_e, \phi_e)$?